# How to programmatically retrieve any number of similarly named post variables

Tags: php, forms, variables

Before getting to my registration page, my users specify te number (X) of group members to be registered. Upon arriving on that page, X registration forms are generated, one for each member. So I have a `first_name1` text field for the first person, then `first_name2`, `first_name3`, etc. In total, X `first_name` fields each with a number at the end of it.

Problem is when retrieving those variables. There can be 20 people, so in my code I won't do:

```
$_POST['first_name1'] 
$_POST['first_name2'] 
...
$_POST['first_name20']
```

Instead, I'd like to do something like:

```
$_POST['first_name.$number']
```

Is it possible in PHP?

Comment: just `"first_name$number"` will do it. The double quotes are the key. More complicated variables require this: `"blah{$_POST["x"]}blah"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrays in your form element names like this:

```
<input name="first_name[]" type="text" />
<input name="first_name[]" type="text" />
<input name="first_name[]" type="text" />
```

In your php you can then access it by iterating over the array:

```
foreach($_POST['first_name'] as $index => $first_name) {
  // Do something with $first_name
}
```

---

*Note:* you can create very complex structures using this method, this isn't just limited to the simple example above. You can even create a multidimensional  array, for example:

```
<input name="user[0][first_name]" type="text" />
<input name="user[0][last_name]" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$first_name_numbered = 'first_name'.$number;
$_POST[$first_name_numbered];
```

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been handled well on the PHP site itself:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650